# How to get long texts of FI held documents?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I need to get the particulars/long text of FI held documents. I tried the 'read_text' function module but had no luck since the held document has the temporary document number.

I tried looking for data in `STXL` and `STXH` tables, I also tried the function modules in FM group `FTXT` and `STXD` but had no luck.

Any other method to achieve that goal?

Comment: If you are working with a temporary document number, I am guessing you need this data in a user exit. If you tell us what that is we might be able to help you better.

Comment: One of the parameters needed on 'read_text' fm is the document number which will be generated when  the document is parked or posted. I made a fi document which is held, i used tcode f-43. then I inserted a long text more particularly, the particulars. how can I get that particulars/ long text?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need the temporary document number which can be get either from F-43 itself or from `RFDT` table.

[image]

In field `SRTFD` you should separate it from username.

[image]

Then run `READ_TEMP_DOCUMENT` FM, after running it you should have your texts in ABAP memory.

To get them use `GET_TEXT_MEMORY`.

```
 ls_uf05a-tempd = '0012312356'.     "doc number
 ls_uf05a-unamd = 'JOHNDOE'.        "username

 CALL FUNCTION 'READ_TEMP_DOCUMENT'
   EXPORTING
     I_UF05A         = ls_uf05a
    TABLES
     T_BKPF          = lt_bkpf
     T_BSEC          = lt_bsec
     T_BSED          = lt_bsed
     T_BSEG          = lt_bseg
     T_BSET          = lt_bset
     T_BSEZ          = lt_bsez
     .

DATA: lt_texts TYPE TABLE OF TCATALOG,
      t_tline TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tline,
      memory_id(30) VALUE 'SAPLSTXD'.

CALL FUNCTION 'GET_TEXT_MEMORY'
  TABLES
    TEXT_MEMORY       = lt_texts.

READ TABLE lt_texts ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<cat>) WITH KEY tdobject = 'BELEG'
                                                           tdid = '0001'
                                                           tdspras = 'E' BINARY SEARCH.
IF sy-subrc = 0.
   memory_id+8(6) = <cat>-id.
ENDIF.

IMPORT tline = t_tline FROM MEMORY ID memory_id.

LOOP AT t_tline ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<tline>).
  WRITE: <tline>-tdline.                                    "showing the texts
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but doesn't work, I have tried that method and I use 'DOC_ITEM' instead beleg, and i have looked into the header of the long text to get the id and object. any other way to get that particulars

Comment: Why do you use `DOC_ITEM` instead beleg? And what do you mean under particulars?

Comment: I tried beleg too, but it doesn't work. I found out that the object for particulars is DOC_ITEM while the text id was Z002, i've seen this in the text header. on the f-43 held document long texts.

Comment: I don't know what *particulars* you are talking about. There is no such entity in SAP. There **are** [long texts](https://imgur.com/a/OCymU) and this code definitely works for them.

Comment: GIve the screenshot for clarity.